# Can't enter text in input with Firefox

Tags: html, firefox

I am trying to log in to http://www.opinionazer.com/en/login with Firefox. With Chrome things work fine, but with Firefox I can't enter any text !

on other pages, there are some inputs and Firefox accepts text, what's the problem with this page ? I am not doing anything complicated really no ?

Thanks

Comment: Weird. It looks like the input's padding hides the text in Firefox but not in Chrome. I am also interested in an explanation.

Comment: @showdev to notify you about the answer, yes it was simply padding hiding the text!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't fill in the fields with Firefox, as well. I'm pretty sure that it's a problem of CSS(design) of the website. I found that parameter "height" in the class (class="form-control pad-tb20-lr-15"), is too low to see your text. As you can see in my print screen if I increase the value of the parameter "height" you are able to see what you write.

Print screen of the HTML code before increase the value of the parameter "height" :

[image]

Print screen of the HTML code after increase the value of the parameter "height" :

[image]

So, the only things that you can do now, it's to use Chrome to login to this website and send this rapport to their contact page to make them fix this problem.

Sorry, i can't help you more.